# What is the longest possible delay between GIF frames?

Tags: gif

I've searched and found no answer, and the [GIF specification](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) is over my head. What is the longest possible delay between frames in a GIF animation?

Comment: You can download the decoder logic and details from the following link - http://www.tune2wizard.com/gif-decoder/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your reference says the delays are 2 byte unsigned integers and the unit is 100ths of a second. So the max duration in seconds would be (2^16-1)/100 = 65535/100 = 655.35s or about 11 minutes.